# WizardPage vs WizardDialog

Tags: java, swt, jface, wizard

In SWT, what is the difference between **WizardPage** and **WizardDialog**
Can some explain please. I couldn't understand fully yet.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WizardDialog` contains one or more `WizardPage` s. Wizards are part of JFace API not SWT.
Different `WizardPage`s can slide back and forth on the same `WizardDialog` by clicking **Back** and **Next** button. Clicking on **Finish** button will close the `WizardDialog`
and clicking on **Cancel** button will abort the operation.

Check this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWizards/article.html#wizards_pages).

Check [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JFaceWizards/index.html) and [here](http://krishnanmohan.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/jface-wizard-explained-enablingdisabling-next-finish-buttons/) for more info on wizards.